# Android L: Transition - create Dialog out of FAB

Tags: android, transition

I would like to create a transtion in an android 21 sdk app with a transition from a FAB to a dialog view within one activity. Where do I start, I only found tutorials on how to make transition between two activities or scene transitions between two layouts. As I understand I would have only one layout in one activity and there a transition from the FAB view to the dialog view.

Can anybody give me some hints on how to implement that?